# serviceworker.js keeps pointing to incorrect path from javascript file

Tags: javascript, service-worker

In my php application I have a file called main.js and in it has a service worker implementation to register a service worker in a web app. This is the sample snippet from the main.js file needed to register a service worker

```
(function () {
  //If serviceWorker supports, then register it.
  if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('http://localhost:88/weburl/serviceWorker.js', { scope: "./" }) //setting scope of sw
    .then(function(registration) {
      console.info('Service worker is registered!');
      checkForPageUpdate(registration); // To check if new content is updated or not
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.error('Service worker failed ', error);
    });
  }
```

This is the path to my project **http://localhost:88/weburl.com/serviceWorker.js**

when I launch the above project it keeps telling

```
A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script. serviceworker.js
```

And on inspecting the element, the base url to the project added in script as shown is never loaded as sampled

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('http://localhost:88/weburl/serviceWorker.js', { scope: "./" }) //setting scope of sw
```

instead I see this that results in error 404 not found

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('./serviceWorker.js', { scope: "./" }) //setting scope of sw
```

please what could be wrong

Answer (score 0):

Can you just try without local host with correct path, I have just given an example below

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/weburl/serviceWorker.js', { scope: "./" })
```

Or look at this link from google - https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/service-workers